# Power Automate: WebCal New Event / Entry / Update trigger

Tags: power-automate

**TL,DR;** Any suggestions / tips to use a **WebCal URL** update as a trigger in a Flow?

**Background:** My 3 children use Schoology for their online learning. They get assignments through this application, but the problem with this is that they have to go to multiple places to get this list and they cannot check off the assignments when they are completed (they just stay in their list after they have submitted and completed the item).

Schoology provides a **WebCal link** to see all of these assignments in a calendar feed and I would like to take all of these entries and add them to **Microsoft To-Do** and allow the use of the functionality there. **Power Automate** does not allow for the usage of **WebCal** links from what I can see. (There is a request [here](https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Power-Automate-Ideas/Use-public-Internet-Calendar-as-trigger/idc-p/29134#M11640) for this functionality.) So my idea was to put the **WebCal** in **Google Calendar**, use the **Google Calendar** trigger **When an event is added to a calendar** to create a **Microsoft To-Do** entry with **Add a to-do (V2)**. The problem is that **Power Automate** does not see new entries with the **Google Calendar** trigger **When an event is added to a calendar**.

In troubleshooting this, I changed the flow source of the **Google Calendar** to one that is manually maintained, created a Google event and **Power Automate** was able to create a **To-Do** list entry. So I know that the Flow is working, it is just that the trigger does not fire for the WebCal.

Any suggestions / tips to use a **WebCal URL** as a trigger in a **Flow**?

Answer (score 0):

As per Google as my understand:

> Google caches web call links for "between 8 and 24th hour"

So that is probably the root of your 'failed to trigger' issue.